# getAttribute('value') when value=""

Tags: javascript, yui

I am using Y.one(selector).getAttribute('value'); to return the value on a page and I am having trouble dealing with cases where value="".

```
var check_value = Y.one(selector).getAttribute('value');
if (check_value != undefined || check_value != null || check_value != "") {
    alert(check_value);
}
```

With all of these checks I am getting an empty alert box when the value of the element I am looking at is "". In this case since I know the value I am looking for is a number I can change the check to just look for a number > 0 and have it work but I was wondering if anyone knew of a method to check for no value for cases where I was not dealing with numeric data.

```
if (check_value >0) {
    alert(check_value);
}
```

This method does work in my case.

Comment: As has been pointed out the first check will always produce bad results because of the ||(or) checks on the same value and I should have been testing with $$(and).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just check for 'truthiness' instead?

```
if (check_value) {
   alert(check_value);
}
```

It's basically the same as your (intended) check, I suppose. And if you need to check for `0` (a Number), just use this:

```
if (check_value || check_value === 0) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: This works for me and gives me the results I need though in my case I need the true vale so will use 

if (check_value) { alert(check_value); }

Comment: @JoeW Of course. ) Updated my answer - and now left wondering why I actually thought about negating that check. )

Comment: you might've been thinking of `!!check_value` that will force it to a boolean value instead of determining it's truthiness.

Comment: truthiness best made up programmin word

Answer (score 2):

If it is an empty string, then it isn't undefined and it isn't null. Since you check if it is not undefined **or** not null **or** not an empty string, then it will pass.

Use `&&` not `||`

Answer (score 1):

You might look at Y.Lang.isValue()

http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Lang.html#method_isValue

Answer (score 0):

Look at the logic in plain english `check_value != undefined || check_value != null || check_value != ""` if it's `undefined or null or ""`, if it's null it's not undefined, if it's blank it's not null, so everything gets through; you're looking for a logical `AND` instead of `OR`

try this:

```
var check_value = Y.one(selector).getAttribute('value');
if (check_value != undefined && check_value != null && check_value != "") {
    alert(check_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the alert because your `if` statement has `OR` (`||`) clauses. In the case that the `value` attribute is an empty string, the last condition (`check_value != ""`) should fail. However, since `""` is not equal to `undefined` the first condition has already returned true, the `if` statements test passes (it won't evaluate the other conditions because it doesn't need to) and the `if` block is executed.

I suspect you actually wanted to use `AND` (`&&`) instead.